# Htaccess www redirect - status codes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i am using this rewrite rule in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

basically it redirects the user to www if he type the adress without the www. (sub-domins excluded).
Is there any other way to do it without htaccess file?

My Problem:

If i navigate the Browser to my Page The first HTTP-Satus code i get is the (www) redirect 301 and then the 200 (for the www.domain.com).
If i try this with, for example. ebay.de the first status code i get is "Pending" and then i get redirected to www.ebay.de with 200.
How they do the www redirect without a 301 htaccess?

Comment: What's the problem with 301 status code? You can use 302 for temporary redirect also

Comment: I would stick to status code 301 since its moved permanently. i.e. a search engine will index just the one with www. if there are somewhere links to the site without www.

Comment: Yes i use the 301 cos its the correct one for this. but my problem is the error-page. the first code i get isnt the 404, its the 301 www redirect. thats what im trying to fix.